# How to send and receive dedicated types in spring-cloud-stream test?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream

I have a simple [spring-cloud-stream](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html) application with this `Function` implementation :

```
@Configuration
public class StarZFunction {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StarZFunction.class);

    @Bean
    public Function<StarZ, StarZ> processEvents() {
        return starZ -> {
            starZ.setVmNr(starZ.getVmNr()*1000);
            starZ.setTuCode(starZ.getTuCode().toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT));
            return starZ;
        };
    }

}
```

And I'm trying to thest this code by simply sending and receiving the object:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes =  SampleApp.class)
@Import({TestChannelBinderConfiguration.class})
public class IntegrationTest1 {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IntegrationTest1.class);

    @Autowired
    private InputDestination input;

    @Autowired
    private OutputDestination output;

    @Test
    void sendAndReceive() {
        StarZ starZ = new StarZ(10, "SBB");
        input.send(new GenericMessage<StarZ>(starZ));
        GenericMessageConverter genericMessageConverter = new GenericMessageConverter();
        assertThat(output.receive().getPayload()).isEqualTo(starZ);
    }

}
```

This fails, because `output.receive().getPayload()` only returns a `byte[]`. How can I get the `StarZ` Object?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the data is converted to json by default. Since I did not find a way to get something like `Message<StarZ>` directly from the API I did the conversion by hand.

```
@Test
void sendAndReceive() {
    StarZ starZ = new StarZ(10, "SBB");
    input.send(new GenericMessage<>(starZ));
    Message<byte[]> messageWithByte = output.receive();

    assertThat(deserializeMessage(messageWithByte)).isEqualTo(starZ);
}

private StarZ deserializeMessage(Message<byte[]> m) {
    LOGGER.info(new String(m.getPayload()));
    try {
        return objectMapper.readValue(m.getPayload(), StarZ.class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Looks a little bit akward, but does the job.
I'm more than happy to accept a better answer though.